# iOS 5 Storyboard with Sign In Overlay (iOS 5.1; Xcode 4.3.3)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4, storyboard

I'm trying to create an iOS (iPhone specific) app where users have to authenticate before accessing the rest of the app. I'm using a Storyboard for the main application which looks like this (broken up into separate lines):

```
(1)        -> NavigationController
(2)  -(o-o)-> OfficesViewController
(3)   -[<-]-> OfficeViewController
```

I also have a separate XIB file called `ScanOverlayViewController` which gets programmatically pushed by the `OfficeViewController` when a user presses on a button. Not sure if it's proper to have Storyboards and XIBs mixed in like this, but it's been working so far.

Anyway, back on topic, I want to put an authentication screen infront of the `NavigaitonController`, but I'm not sure how.

I've tried placing an unlinked view in the Storyboard and setting it as the initial view. I then placed a hidden button and made a segue to the `NavigationController`. In code I tried having the controller perform the segue but the seque wasn't actually being performed even though the view had appeared properly.

I then tried to make the authentication view it's own separate XIB and initializing the controller in the app delegate and setting its view as a sub view of the app delegate. That just resulted in the app going directly to the `OfficesViewController` view as if I hadn't done anything.

Is there a specific way of doing this properly so it works with Storyboards?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here's my current app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
AuthenticationViewController *authenticationViewController = [[AuthenticationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthenticationViewController" bundle:nil];

if (authenticationViewController) {
    NSLog(@"Should have generated %@", authenticationViewController);
};

[[[application keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:authenticationViewController animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

The controller does get allocated and initialized, but it's just not showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the `NavigaitonController` as your initial view controller, then present the authentication screen modally if required. You can do this in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Mixing XIB files and storyboards is fine, storyboards get turned into XIB (or nib) files anyway, they just have some extra meta data. Mix and match as makes sense.

E.g.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([self needsAuthentication])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            AuthVC *authVC = [[AuthVC alloc] init];
            [[UIWindow keyWindow].rootViewController presentModalViewController:authVC animated:YES];
        });
    }
    // anything else
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I hate to sound dumb on this, but do you have a code sample of what you mean? I roughly know what you're talking about, but my brain is starting to fail me... Right now my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is only returning `YES` (because I commented everything else out).

Comment: I made the changes as per your example, but nothing happens. The application just starts up and goes directly to the `OfficesViewController`. I've updated my question with my current version of the app delegate.

Comment: awesome it worked! Quick sub question, why does it have to be an async operation? Does that mean that the `UINavigationController` is not fully initialized and that's why the sign in window is added to the main queue?